# Want to change font color in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Not sure what wrong with code below, i want to give white color to the text

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.cell import Cell

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx', read_only=False)
keep_sheets = ['sheet3','sheet2','sheet1']
for sheetName in wb.sheetnames:
    if sheetName in keep_sheets:
        ws = wb[sheetName]
        print(ws)
        fill_pattern = PatternFill(start_color='#4F81BD',
                   end_color='#4F81BD',
                   fill_type='solid')

        for col in range(1, colindex(sheetName)):  # 1 to 10 corresponds to A to J
            cell = ws.cell(row=1, column=col)
            cell.fill = fill_pattern
            cell.font = Font(color=colors.WHITE, bold=True)

# Save changes
wb.save('updated_file.xlsx')
```

on trying to apply I get error as below

```
ValueError: Colors must be aRGB hex values
```

Comment: the error tells you that "Colors must be aRGB hex values"  but you are just providing RGB values. You are missing the alpha channel

Comment: I don't believe your colors should start with the `#`. Either supply a 6 or 8 digit hex code like `4F81BD` or `004F81BD`. I believe you are failing the regex specified [here] (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/openpyxl/styles/colors.html) (`aRGB_REGEX = re.compile("^([A-Fa-f0-9]{8}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{6})$")`) where the hash character is not included in the check.

Comment: As @JNevill alludes,  just remove the '#' from the hex colour values so you have; `start_color='4F81BD', end_color='4F81BD'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me:

```py
fill_pattern = PatternFill(start_color='4F81BD',
                   end_color='4F81BD',
                   fill_type='solid')

for col in range(3, colindex(sheetName)): 
            cell = ws.cell(row=5, column=col)
            cell.fill = fill_pattern
            cell.font = Font(color='FFFFFF', bold=True)
            cell.value = cell.value.replace("_"," ") 
            cell.value = cell.value.title()
            print("done")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with you `cell.font`. So `color.WHITE` needs to be in RGB

so updated code must be:

`cell.font = Font(color=colors.Color(colors.WHITE.get_hex_color()), bold=True)`

Comment: Its OK to use `color=colors.WHITE` in the Font object

Comment: ah yes sorry for that, i tried giving it  naive approach, thanks for  that.